# Unity Changing the button image by clicking

Tags: c#

Well, I already know that Unity itself has the Sprite Swap function, for that, but I wanted it to click when I changed the image and returned the old one only when it closed the window that was opened, or if I clicked it again on the icon, I tried to several ways so I turned to a helpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video link:- https://youtu.be/-H7j3vdKl8A.

Visit github if u dont undertand it here.
https://github.com/NareshBisht/Unity-UI-Shop-Select-2-UI-object-at-same-time/blob/master/ButtonAnimationHold.cs

Thank you.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

//*************************Script to select one "Category(say Weapon)" UI Button till anathor category button(say Vehicles) is pressed.********************************//  

/*
 * Steps to be followed to make this script work
 * Select All the Category Buttons (for example:- Suppose u r builiding a shop UI then Select all Category button Like Helics, Weapons  -- refer to video link above;
 * Now tag all these category button as same (say UI_CategoryButtons).
 * Attach this script to all the UI_category button.
 * the script will aotomatically add Button, Animator, Image component to the Ui Gameobjects.
 * now select Animation in Transition tab.
 * now press the Auto genrate Animation in Button component tab.
 * now, set Transition from Animation to none in button Tab.
 * Now, Do the above step for Sub category UI element too (for eg do for Apache, Tiger, f-22 etc which is the sub category of Helics --- refer video)
 * open Animation window and Animate ur Ui elements.
 * ur good to go now.
 */

[RequireComponent(typeof(Button))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Image))]
public class ButtonAnimationHold : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public float TransitionTime = 0.3f;  //Time taken to transition from one animation state to anathor.

    private Animator MyAnim;      //reference to animator attacted to the UI gameObject.

    private void Start()
    {
        MyAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        PlayNoramlState();      //Playing normal state at beginning.
    }

    public void HighlightThisButton_UnhighlightRest()    //called when button is pressed (Called by OnPointerClick() defined below)
    {
        string TagOfPressedButton = gameObject.tag;  //the tag of the button pressed by user.

        foreach (Button button in gameObject.GetComponentInParent<Transform>().root.gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Button>())   //searching the gameobject with tag as in TagOfPressedButton inside the canvas which contain all UI element.
        {                                                                                                                           //we search inside Canvas to improve perf.
            if(button.gameObject.tag == TagOfPressedButton && button.gameObject != this.gameObject)     //selecting gameobjects with same tag(tag of button which was pressed) execpt the one which was pressed and then playing normal state in all selected GO.  
            {
                button.gameObject.GetComponent<ButtonAnimationHold>().PlayNoramlState();       //Playing normal state in all UI gameObject with same tag except the one which called it.
            }
        }

        MyAnim.Play("Pressed");  //Playing Pressed state in the UI element that was pressed.

    }

    public void PlayNoramlState()
    {
        MyAnim.CrossFadeInFixedTime("Normal", TransitionTime);      //smoothly transitioning to Normal state; 
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)      //Called when pointer hover over the Ui elemnt;
    {
        if(MyAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Normal"))      //Playing highlighted state only when it is in normal state and not when it is in Pressed state.
        {
            MyAnim.CrossFadeInFixedTime("Highlighted", TransitionTime);    //smoothly transitioning to Highlighted state; 
        }
    }


    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)  
    {
        if (MyAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Highlighted") || MyAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Normal"))  //Playing Normal state only when it is in Highlighted state and not when it is in Pressed state
        {
            MyAnim.CrossFadeInFixedTime("Normal", TransitionTime);  //smoothly transitioning to Normal state; 
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)   //called when button is pressed that is pointer down and pointer up both have to be done over button
    {
        HighlightThisButton_UnhighlightRest();
    }
}


//video link 
//https://youtu.be/-H7j3vdKl8A
```

Comment: In the previous code, it was totally annoying to go and individually select each UI button and then drop the script in OnClick(). so I edited it a little, now u don't have to go and drop the script in onclick() every time just drop the script on UI element. for more info read the step written in script as comment.